# Is it a iOS or FB requirement to give users the ability to log out if using FB sdk for single feature of app?

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

The iOS app asks for the user to authenticate a related Facebook app if they want to post a comment within the iOS app. They do not have to authenticate or login in to FB to use the iOS overall app, or to view comments. Only to post comments or a new thread.

My question is:

**Do I have to* give them the ability to "log out" of FB once they've provided the authentication?**

I'm using the standard Facebook SDK and their identity currently remains within the app until that times out, the length of time I assume is set by the Facebook SDK.

*I want to avoid failing the iOS approval process because of a lack of a log out option.

Answer (score 0):

Article 6 on [Facebook developers policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#policies) states:

> Your website must offer an explicit "Log Out" option that also logs
>   the user out of Facebook.

In the Facebook iOS SDK [authenticate tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/), they say

> Next you should give people using your app a way to logout from Facebook and clear their session information

If you don't have a reason for not implementing a logout button, I would strongly recommend to add it.